# does the range operator guarantees order?

Tags: go

Let's say , I am concatenating structs into an array with an `append()` call. Will the **range** operator during the read process guarantee the same order as elements were added to the array?

```
var array_of_structs []*some_struct_t
build_array(&array_of_structs)
for i,value := range array_of_structs {
    ..whatever, but I need `i` to be i=0,1,2... N in an ordered way
}
```

What do the specs say? I am going to calculate money, so I need to be sure it is ordered.

Comment: "What do the specs say?" Read [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec).

Comment: @peterSO, it's Google's fault, I googled , but didn't get the results

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a slice it is guaranteed by the spec

> For an array, pointer to array, or slice value a, the index iteration values are produced in increasing order, starting at element index 0. If at most one iteration variable is present, the range loop produces iteration values from 0 up to len(a)-1 and does not index into the array or slice itself. For a nil slice, the number of iterations is 0.

Reference:

- https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_range

Comment: Worth noting here that `range` over /maps/ is intentionally nondeterministically ordered.

Answer (score 0):

You do not "concatenate into an array with an append()" – you append() to slices ([3]S vs. []S).

> If the capacity of slice is not large enough to fit the additional values,
>   append allocates a new, sufficiently large underlying array that fits
>   both the existing slice elements and the additional values. Otherwise,
>   append re-uses the underlying array.

The originating array may thus not contain all elements appended.